# Pycharm failing to resolve django urls

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm running Pycharm 2016.1 and working on a project with Django 1.8. Usually PyCharm has this neat feature that can autocomplete `{% url %}` tags for you in templates, however the inspection has been failing for me for a while now and won't even discover the urls at all, giving me this error:

[image: unresolved url]

The project works fine and Django discovers all the urls when running, so the problem should be with PyCharm.

Comment: Does it do this for every url or just those of a particular app?

Comment: @Sayse any url, even the standard {% url 'admin:index' %} from djangos admin-app.

Comment: You could try `File > Invalidate Caches  / Restart`

Comment: @Sayse no changes :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was also driving me nuts. The only thing that worked for me was to delete two things (after closing Pycharm).

1. Delete the entire .idea folder within the project directory.
2. Delete the **pycache** directory within the project directory (if exists)

I re-opened the project and every reference issue I had went away.

Hope this helps!

NOTE: I had previously tried:

- Restarting Pycharm
- Invalidating Caches
- Adjusting project preferences and tinkered with Django settings as well as disabling then re-enabling Django support
- Adjusting namespaces, settings.py file etc..

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried namespacing your URLs? In your base urls.py file, if you are including urls from other apps, I'd add the **namespace** and/or **app_name** arguments, e.g.:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^author-polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace='author-polls')),
    url(r'^publisher-polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace='publisher-polls')),

]
```

And then, in your template, try

```
{% url 'author-polls:author_poll_list' author.pk %}
```

where **author_poll_list** is the name of your specific view. For more specific info on namespacing see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces)

One thing to mention is, is any other template tag completion working in your templates e.g. static tags, template includes etc? If they are not then it might be that you need to mark your template folders as template folders in

> Settings > Project > Project Structure

I hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

You may want to have a quick look at: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-19152 and try to upgrade your PyCharm to version **`2016.1.4`** which includes a fix for this issue. It looks like a similar problem to what you are/were seeing.

Comment: I tried namespacing, however, it seems whatever I do in the actual urls file doesnt make a difference for PyCharm. And yes, somewhat frustratringly, any other auto-complete function for static files, template tags, filters etc. works fine. I tried making a blank project to see if url-resolving works and it sure did, but I cant seem to see any difference in setup.

Comment: Probably not going to help but could you try disabling/re-enabling Django support for your project by going to **Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Django** . Un-check Django support, **Apply**, then re-enable. It will ask you to provide the location to the project root and settings file again. Once that is done it should rebuild your project structure, click on _Show Structure_ and see if it can see any of your URLs there.